# GNU MP best alternative for functions that should "return" something

Tags: c++, gmp

So, let's say you want to write a C++ program and implement a function which returns the incremented value of a variable by 1; you'd probably do something like this:

```
int next(int n) {
    return n+1;
}
```

When trying to do the same thing with mpz_t's, you'll have noticed that the compiler complains about the fact that mpz_t represents an array. Therefore, an alternative is needed.

What I'd do spontaneously is to declare all required variables in the global scope and make the return type of my functions "void", so that the functions only modify globally defined variables.

Is this good? Are there better alternatives?

EDIT: I've just found that GMP variables are passed by reference. Problem solved.

Comment: Global variables should be avoided if possible, because they make it difficult to debug, maintain, or extend the program.

Comment: That's not what I would call `inc` but what I call `next`. `next` returns the next number after the argument `n`. For `inc` I would expect it to increment the argument itself: `int next(int n) { return n + 1; } void inc(int *n) { *n = *n + 1; }`. But since this is C++ we can do much better. We have `operator++` and can do both pre and post increment and use references and even move semantic.

Comment: GMP comes with a C++ interface in gmpxx.h, which defines a type mpz_class which behaves more like you expect. You can find alternate C++ interfaces in boost, etc.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes, this seems to be the default usage. Nevertheless, I tried to get a different point across.

Comment: I hope you pass along local variables via pointer/reference and not global.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You do not hope in vain. The catastrophe may yet be averted.